# Is this question about advertising On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question about actor endorsments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/have-celebrities-endorsed-products-in-other-countries-that-have-eventually-been) doesn't seem like a good fit but seeing as we have a question asked about [product placement's first occurence](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/first-movie-with-product-placement)  I wanted to get the community's feel for whether or not this question is valid for us.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I feel that there's a disconnect between the two questions mentioned.  The Product Placement question is about what the first product placement **in a movie** was.  The new question seems to be more about commersials and celebrity endorsements of a product rather than a movie or tv series.  I don't think it's ever been brought up before, but I personally consider commercials **off-topic**, and this question along with them.

Comment: Agree! Commercials should be off-topic. Not just because of their superficial nature, but they are too local in time and space, and questions could easily be abused for sneaky advertising.

Answer (score 1):

As an individual i think this should be On-Topic here. Even we doesn't have any other SE Site where it belongs. And i think `product placement's` is directly connected to TV . And our title say `Movies and TV`. But it should be decided by community and i thought to express my opinion of favor.

Comment: But the reason of "There is no other SE" is a flawed one at best.  Just because we don't have an SE for the colour green, does that mean we should post all questions about green on UE.SE?

Comment: But in my thinking as compare to other SE Sites , we are the best suited for it.

Comment: It's a question dealing with actors and commercials, which would fall under the umbrella of Television

Comment: To be honest, as a movie goer and tv consumer, questions about commercials just don't interest me. Besides mostly trivial questions, such as "who was in this commercial", what deep, analytical questions can you ask about a commercial? Also, to reiterate tyler, it's not our job to find a home for every question, just to make sure we keep good, interesting, on-topic questions here.

Comment: I second the "what deep, analytical questions can you ask about a commercial?"